# Linq - Grouping a list and get more than one data from it

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I have a timetable list. I want to pull two data by grouping over this list. However, I was not successful. My data.

| id | xid | date | yid | gid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 2022-08-19 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 31 | 2022-08-18 | 6 | 5 |
| 3 | 30 | 2022-08-17 | 6 | 3 |
| 4 | 32 | 2022-08-18 | 6 | 5 |

My code

```
_contex.timetable.where(i=>i.yid==6).DistinctBy(i => i.xid).Select(i => new { i.xid, i.gid, i.date}).ToListAsync();
```

but null value or error. What i want to do.

| xid | date | yid | gid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 2022-08-19 | 5 | 3 |
| 31 | 2022-08-18 | 6 | 5 |
| 32 | 2022-08-18 | 6 | 5 |

I want to get the last data of the date and also the gid fields.

Sorry for my bad English, I hope I explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I think you want to get the data of `Id`,`date`,`gid` from latest date row which group by `xid`, So you can try to refer this code:

```
var result = await _context.timetables.GroupBy(x => x.xid)
              .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(r => r.date)
               .Select(a=> new {a.Id,a.date,a.gid}).FirstOrDefault())
                .ToListAsync();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You group them up by `xid` and pick the latest date row from each group.

```
var result = context.timetable
                .GroupBy(t => t.xid)
                .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.date).First())
                .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I used both ways, it returns null result. But I need the data as follows. List `{id=6,date=2022-08-19,gid=5}`